# How do you watch or evaluate an expression in xcode like visual studio's immediate window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

In MS visual studio we just right click add watch.

How does one do this in Xcode?

Comment: The problem is I don't know when the variable is changed. If I know I'll just use regular breakpoint.

Answer (score 40):

### Use the `po` command in the Debug area

Set up a breakpoint on the relevant area of code, then when the program stops at the breakpoint, enter commands in the Console in the Debug Area. 
The relevant command is **`po`** (*print object*) followed by the expression you want to evaluate.

If the Debug window is not visible in XCode, you can show it via the top menu:

`'View' -> 'Debug Area' -> 'Activate Console'` (*XCode v8.x*)

#### Example

To evaluate an expression like `var1/var2` where `var1` and `var2` are both doubles, enter the following in the Console:

```
po var1/var2
```

The Console will return something like:

```
(double) $2 = 3.085 [no Objective-C description available]
```

### Showing object properties

You can also return a particular property of an object currently used in the code at that breakpoint:

```
po [bankInfo city]
```

And it will return something like:

```
(id) $4 = 0x000069e8 Testville
```

Note though that the Console doesn't seem to like the dot notation and prefers the square brackets when applicable. For example, this returns an error for me:

```
po bankInfo.city
```

I hope this is what you've been looking for.

Comment: @gideon You should mark this the accepted answer (for Visual Studio people like the op and me)

Answer (score 15):

Gabe's answer is almost there but missing one crucial detail: Select **Debugger Output** . By default the bottom option is set to Target Output, so the `po` command doesn't show you anything.

Here is a *sandwich app* from a tutorial I'm debugging:

[image: eval expression screenshot in xcode]

Being an xcode newbie and coming from a MS Visual Studio Background, I wanted exactly what the OP was looking for. While playing around from reading Gabe's answer I selected `Debugger Output` and got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

My seniors told to use NSLog(@variable)..........

Comment: Can we do that on some immediate window?

Comment: Can we do that on immediate window like in vb.net?

Comment: the OP is asking for a way to view expressions and variables when a breakpoint is hit. I know exactly what he's talking about since I've used visual studio for very very long and there is immediate window which will allow you to code as if you were in a REPL console with the current stack frame in context. So you can see variable values etc in there **based on where your breakpoint is**. Putting logging calls, while useful is not really good, you are changing code and you need to remember to remove them once you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Set some breakpoints in the begginning of the looping and functions. Once u click on the breakpoint(one similar to arrow) button in the editor window the "Build and debug tool" will get enabled. You can then go to the debugger by clicking the debugger icon. on the right of the debugger window variables will be visible select self->then the instance variable u r going to set watch point.Right click on that and select "watch variable".A trigger point will be set and you will be notified with the value of the variable when changed.

Comment: Did that work.Or else you can see the pages on Debugging in "Objective C for dummies" book for better understanding.They have explained clearly of how to set debugging.

Comment: Clicking the breakpoint makes the breakpoint become pale. Don't know what that mean.

Comment: I am just trying to watch expression. I am already able to watch local variables.

Comment: Yeah, was looking for a way to watch expressions as well, not simple variables.

Answer (score 1):

As fas as i understand you would like to see when a variable is changing. For this make a breakpoint and right click on it and choose `Edit Breakpoint`. A window will appear:

[image]

Make sure you choose the right **action** like `Debugger Command` or `Log Message` and check the tick down at the options `Automatically continue after evaluating`. So you get some kind of action (e.g. logging, sound, etc) and wont stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the variable changes, use a "watch":

1. Set a breakpoint somewhere in the class in question;
2. Run the app in the debugger and let it stop at your breakpoint; and
3. Go to the "Variables" view in the left side of the bottom "Debug" panel and right click on the property in question and choose "Watch".

For example, here, I've stopped at a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad`, and added a "watch" for `total`:

[image: Watch]

(This is Swift, but the same is true for Objective-C, too.)

Now, if I "continue" execution ([image]), Xcode will pause whenever this property changes and I can see at what line of code `total` is changing, the stack trace to get to that point, etc.