# I'm trying to pass data between view controllers, but only half of my 16 variables pass?

Tags: swift, xcode

Essentially, I'm trying to get 16 different variables to be passed from one view controller to the other, but only the bottom 8 opponent variables are passed. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why only those 8 specifically (which have "opponent" in common) are being passed. I'm new to XCode so anything that can help me out would be great. The print lines were testing to see if the variables were being sent with the first not working and the second working as intended.

```
    //
//  ThirdViewController.swift
//  rally
//
//  Created by GBernero on 12/6/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 GBernero. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emptyTennisCourt: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOpponent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPlayer: UILabel!

    var playerWinners = 0 //holds total amount of winners player has hit
    var playerShortWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners play has hit short
    var playerDeepWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners play has hit deep
    var playerErrors = 0 //holds total amount of errors play has hit
    var playerErrorsLeft = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit left
    var playerErrorsRight = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit right
    var playerErrorsDeep = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit deep
    var playerErrorsNet = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit in the net
    var opponentWinners = 0 //holds total amount of winners opponent has hit
    var opponentShortWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners opponent has hit short
    var opponentDeepWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners opponent has hit deep
    var opponentErrors = 0 //holds total amount of errors opponent has hit
    var opponentErrorsLeft = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit left
    var opponentErrorsRight = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit right
    var opponentErrorsDeep = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit deep
    var opponentErrorsNet = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit in the net

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! SixthViewController
        dvc.playerErrorsDeep = self.playerErrorsDeep
        print("segueing from self \(self.playerErrorsDeep) to dvc: \(dvc.playerErrorsDeep)")
        dvc.playerErrorsNet = self.playerErrorsNet
        dvc.playerErrorsLeft = self.playerErrorsLeft
        dvc.playerErrorsRight = self.playerErrorsRight
        dvc.playerErrors = self.playerErrors
        dvc.playerShortWinners = self.playerShortWinners
        dvc.playerDeepWinners = self.playerDeepWinners
        dvc.playerWinners = self.playerWinners
        dvc.opponentErrorsDeep = self.opponentErrorsDeep
        print("segueing to dvc2: \(dvc.opponentErrorsDeep)")
        dvc.opponentErrorsNet = self.opponentErrorsNet
        dvc.opponentErrorsLeft = self.opponentErrorsLeft
        dvc.opponentErrorsRight = self.opponentErrorsRight
        dvc.opponentErrors = self.opponentErrors
        dvc.opponentShortWinners = self.opponentShortWinners
        dvc.opponentDeepWinners = self.opponentDeepWinners
        dvc.opponentWinners = self.opponentWinners

    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false) //removes back button from access by user

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tennis_background.jpg")!) //sets background of view controller to the background image


        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsDeep += 1
        print("deep \(playerErrors), \(playerErrorsDeep)")
    }
    @IBAction func youErrorLeft(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsLeft += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorRight(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsRight += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youWinnerDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerWinners += 1
        playerDeepWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youWinnerShort(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerWinners += 1
        playerShortWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorNet(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsNet += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsDeep += 1
        print( "it happens")
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorLeft(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsLeft += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorRight(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsRight += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentWinnerDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentWinners += 1
        opponentDeepWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentWinnerShort(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentWinners += 1
        opponentShortWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorNet(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsNet += 1
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


}
```

Comment: Before you worry about `dvc.playerErrorsDeep`, did you look at `self.playerErrorsDeep`? Was that what you thought it should be? If not, set a breakpoint where you set _that_ and make sure (a) it's getting set properly; and (b) it's not getting reset somewhere accidentally.

Comment: Incidentally, if you're not sure where this variable is changing, an Xcode "watch" can be very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41196124/1271826

Comment: I've found that the self.playerErrorsDeep properly updates on the first view controller, but there seems to be an issue upon transferring to the second view controller that the variable there does not receive that value and sits at 0 forever.

Comment: Let's get this right, you're saying that if you update your `print` statement to say `print("segueing from self \(self.playerErrorsDeep) to dvc: \(dvc.playerErrorsDeep)")`, that is says that the `self` rendition is non-zero but the `dvc` rendition is zero?!? And these are simple `Int` types? Bottom line, I really do not think the problem is in the code above, but rather some confusion about when `self.playerErrorsDeep` and/or `self.playerErrorsDeep` change values. E.g. Maybe you have some other code somewhere which is resetting `dvc`'s rendition or something like that.

Comment: We need a [minimal, reproducible example, a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. The code above is insufficient to manifest the issue. There is something else going on. (As an aside, the exercise of creating a MCVE is extremely useful, because in the process of figuring out what you have to add/remove to reproduce the problem, you will generally end up solving the problem. So, either make a copy of your project and start ripping out unrelated stuff until the problem goes away, or take a blank project and start adding stuff until you can reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake. print("segueing from self \(self.playerErrorsDeep) to dvc: \(dvc.playerErrorsDeep)") returns "segueing from self 0 to dvc: 0" not what I thought it should return at this point "segueing from self 1 to dvc: 0"

Comment: I have added my entire view controller's code so that you can see it!

Comment: You say that "returns 'segueing from self 0 to dvc: 0'". Then, that's clearly the problem, no?

Comment: Yes, but I can't solve it. That seems to be the problem (now I see), but I'm not sure what's wrong with my code! I've had this issue for almost a week, but I'm new to XCode so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've added my entire view controller's code above if you would be able to spot an issue there?

Comment: (Not to be cranky, but in the future, rather than posting your entire view controller, you should distill it down to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem. And that's not just the code, but tell us the precise steps to reproduce the problem in a blank project. But we really don't need to see all 16 properties or all 12 `@IBAction`. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Thank you, Rob! Sorry about overloading the code.

Comment: No problem. By the way, I now see that you posted a duplicative question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41203743/1271826. That's frustrating to spend the time answering this one only to realize you asked it again elsewhere. Next time, delete the first question before asking another. Or put a comment there to say what you're doing.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry to have wasted your time. Your explanation here was very in depth and helped me a lot! It also helped me fix the double segue. Thank you. I had assumed you'd left because I was looking at your profile and I could tell you were very busy/active in this community, and I wasn't sure if my question was a waste of time. Again, I'm sorry to have had you go out of your way to help me unnecessarily, but your explanation has helped me A LOT! Thank you, Rob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted a ton of code and tell us that when you replaced that `print` statement with:

```
print("segueing from self \(self.playerErrorsDeep) to dvc: \(dvc.playerErrorsDeep)")
```

... that it then displayed:

> segueing from self 0 to dvc: 0

So, the problem just appears that `playerErrorsDeep` is `0` by the time `prepareForSegue` is called. So the problem isn't "why isn't `dvc`'s value getting set?" but rather "why is `playerErrorsDeep` `0`?"

Let me ask this question: Is the control that calls `yourErrorDeep` also have a segue attached to it? If you have both segue and `@IBAction` (or multiple `@IBAction`), you have no assurances the order that they're called.

Instead of having a control that has both `@IBAction` and segue, you should remove the segue from the button, and have the `@IBAction` programmatically invoke the segue when its done updating the value. So, you should:

- Remove the segue between the button and the next scene;
- Instead, add the segue between the view controllers, themselves, by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the view controller icon above the "third" scene to the "sixth" scene:

  [image: segue]
- Select that segue and give it an identifier:

  [image: identifier]
- Have your `@IBAction` do whatever updates you want, and then programmatically perform the segue:

  ```
  @IBAction func youErrorDeep(_ sender: Any) {
      playerErrors += 1
      playerErrorsDeep += 1
      print("deep \(playerErrors), \(playerErrorsDeep)")

      performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSixth", sender: self)
  }
  ```

This will ensure that the `@IBAction` will be performed first, and then it will programmatically invoke the segue to the next scene. By that point, `playerErrorsDeep` will have the value you expected it to have.