# My variable value is different than the value the prepareForSegue takes when transferring?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

Essentially, my variable (playerErrors) is updated by a button push and then the view controller is segued to the next with data transferring. However, the variable's value (which should go up by 1 from 0 for example) transfers as 0 (as if the button wasn't pushed). I have 16 variables in my code that I'm trying to transfer, but oddly half (8) of them DO work and the ones that work are all for the opponent's values. The 8 that don't work are player values (like playerErrors).

I'm new to XCode. I'm taking a class in High School where we're learning to code for the first time, so I'm not very good at it yet, but I've had this issue for days and I cannot solve it! I've included my view controller's code below.

When youErrorDeep is triggered, it prints "segueing from self 0 to dvc: 0".

```
//
//  ThirdViewController.swift
//  rally
//
//  Created by GBernero on 12/6/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 GBernero. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emptyTennisCourt: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOpponent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPlayer: UILabel!

    var playerWinners = 0 //holds total amount of winners player has hit
    var playerShortWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners play has hit short
    var playerDeepWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners play has hit deep
    var playerErrors = 0 //holds total amount of errors play has hit
    var playerErrorsLeft = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit left
    var playerErrorsRight = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit right
    var playerErrorsDeep = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit deep
    var playerErrorsNet = 0 //holds amount of errors play has hit in the net
    var opponentWinners = 0 //holds total amount of winners opponent has hit
    var opponentShortWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners opponent has hit short
    var opponentDeepWinners = 0 //holds amount of winners opponent has hit deep
    var opponentErrors = 0 //holds total amount of errors opponent has hit
    var opponentErrorsLeft = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit left
    var opponentErrorsRight = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit right
    var opponentErrorsDeep = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit deep
    var opponentErrorsNet = 0 //holds amount of errors opponent has hit in the net

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! SixthViewController
        dvc.playerErrorsDeep = self.playerErrorsDeep
        print("segueing from self \(self.playerErrorsDeep) to dvc: \(dvc.playerErrorsDeep)")
        dvc.playerErrorsNet = self.playerErrorsNet
        dvc.playerErrorsLeft = self.playerErrorsLeft
        dvc.playerErrorsRight = self.playerErrorsRight
        dvc.playerErrors = self.playerErrors
        dvc.playerShortWinners = self.playerShortWinners
        dvc.playerDeepWinners = self.playerDeepWinners
        dvc.playerWinners = self.playerWinners
        dvc.opponentErrorsDeep = self.opponentErrorsDeep
        print("segueing to dvc2: \(dvc.opponentErrorsDeep)")
        dvc.opponentErrorsNet = self.opponentErrorsNet
        dvc.opponentErrorsLeft = self.opponentErrorsLeft
        dvc.opponentErrorsRight = self.opponentErrorsRight
        dvc.opponentErrors = self.opponentErrors
        dvc.opponentShortWinners = self.opponentShortWinners
        dvc.opponentDeepWinners = self.opponentDeepWinners
        dvc.opponentWinners = self.opponentWinners

    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false) //removes back button from access by user

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "tennis_background.jpg")!) //sets background of view controller to the background image


        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsDeep += 1
        print("deep \(playerErrors), \(playerErrorsDeep)")
    }
    @IBAction func youErrorLeft(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsLeft += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorRight(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsRight += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youWinnerDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerWinners += 1
        playerDeepWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youWinnerShort(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerWinners += 1
        playerShortWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func youErrorNet(_ sender: Any)
    {
        playerErrors += 1
        playerErrorsNet += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsDeep += 1
        print( "it happens")
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorLeft(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsLeft += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorRight(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsRight += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentWinnerDeep(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentWinners += 1
        opponentDeepWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentWinnerShort(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentWinners += 1
        opponentShortWinners += 1
    }

    @IBAction func opponentErrorNet(_ sender: Any)
    {
        opponentErrors += 1
        opponentErrorsNet += 1
    }




    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */


}
```

Comment: Have you tried manually coding the segue instead of relying on the storyboard?

Comment: I don't know how to do that! I'm new and we've only learned how to use the storyboard in class, I think.

Comment: Try setting Xcode breakpoints in `youWinnerDeep(_:)`, and in `prepare(for:sender:)`. If `prepare(for:sender:)` gets called before `youWinnerDeep(_:)`, then the `playerErrors` variable won't have been updated in the local `ThirdViewController` before it gets copied to `SixthViewController`.

Comment: Well it's simple enough to look it up on SO. Anyway, the reason I ask is because you seem to be executing the same exact code for each variable, and since you are using storyboard segues, I am not sure if it is guaranteed that your IBAction will be executed before your segue

Comment: Yeah exactly what @ChrisVig said

Comment: Ah, I see what you two are saying! I think that might be the issue. How can I guarantee prepareForSegue to occur before my buttons?

Comment: I think the only way you can is through manually coding your segues to perform after your operations in your IBAction funcs

Comment: Agree with what @Benjamin said. In `yourWinnerDeep(_:)`, call [`performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) _after_ you update `playerErrors`. That should guarantee it gets updated first.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like you're talking to a child (to some degree you are, haha), but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. What would I need to add explicitly? (I'm very very new to coding, sorry!)

Comment: Since this is your second question within a day, my suggestion? (1) Cut back on passing 16 variables in a segue. (2) Learn the entire life cycle of view controllers, views, and storyboard segues. (3) Debug things one thing at a time. (Please, I'm not talking to a child, just speaking from 35 years of IT wisdom.) Your last question spoke about half of those 16 variables not passing. This question speaks about a single value not passing. My best advice is to get it down about **how** segues work with **one** variable, then work through multiples. Good luck!

Comment: @dfd I think he is quite overwhelmed with this already haha. Perhaps one bite at a time. But yes, all good suggestions.

Comment: I agree. Hope I didn't sound snarky. I'm just trying to help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I'm in an intro class for coding at my high school and I don't think I'm very good at it yet. I'll try to learn more as I go. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not going to repeat it here (as others have answered the question here), but I answered the duplicate question with step by step instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41203965/1271826.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with something like this:

```
@IBAction func youErrorDeep(_ sender: Any){
    playerErrors += 1
    playerErrorsDeep += 1
    print("deep \(playerErrors), \(playerErrorsDeep)")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueForYouErrorDeep", sender: self) //instead of "segueForYourErrorDeep" use the identifier for the correct segue
}
```

You would have to give each segue a unique identifier, but this way you can still use the storyboard to a certain extent.

This also ensures that the segue is executed after the operations.

If you're unsure how to give a segue an identifier, all you have to do is click on the segue graphic and under attributes set the identifier to an arbitrary string.

Comment: What do I do with the Identifier string you put in? And I would have to do this with every button? Do I need to remove all the segues I put on my storyboard (14)?

Comment: No no, all you have to do is click on each segue, give it an identifier and then reflect that identifier in your code (I will update my code to show you where)

Comment: Also, I should get rid of that big prepareForSegue list of dvc/self data transfers, or no?

Comment: Well the way you are doing it currently, you need to keep that part. Otherwise the values won't be transferred to your new VC.

Comment: OK! I'll try this and report back what happens. Thanks so much for your help so far. I REALLY appreciate it. This has been bothering me for days.

Comment: Cool. I'll be offline for the next couple of hours, but let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: Hi. Two things. First, it seems to work now for youErrorDeep, but none of the other buttons. Instead, this seems to not crash the app, but it freezes the app and gives me an error in xcode that says: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and prints out: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) . Also, when it transfers, it seems to segue once with nothing happening, and then it segues again and updates the value.

Comment: Sorry, correction: I got it to work for all the buttons, but it's still doing this odd double transfer segue.

Comment: Hey. Keep in mind you have to put the code that I gave you in every other IBAction and change the identifier for each one. If you do that properly your first error shouldn't occur, but let me know if you have done that already. Secondly, you need to only execute the segue once. You need to make sure that the segue on the storyboard is not active, but rather waits for itself to be called. If it is active, then it will be called once when you tap on the button and then once again in your code, giving you that issue.

Comment: How do I make the segues on the storyboard inactive? Do I uncheck "animates"?

Comment: Anyways, thank you SO much. I cannot tell you how much I appreciate this. This has relieved me so much stress because I was worried I could never get it to work. You rock!!

Comment: No problem! But my work here is not done until you have no more problems. I actually left something out in my explanation. Instead of having segues from an item to another view controller, what you need to have is segues from view controller to view controller. That way they are never called until you call them via code. This will require you to change all of them sadly, but everything else will be the same. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling `peformSegueWithIdentifier:sender` anywhere in your code, so I assume that you are triggering the segue directly from the action outlet in Interface Builder.

This won't work where you need to execute some code on the button press, since the segue may occur before the `@IBAction` method executes.

You should remove the segue from the action outlet, create a segue from your View Controller object in Interface Builder, give this segue an identifier and the you can initiate it from your `@IBAction` method using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`.

Also, for readability and maintainability, I strongly suggest you create a class to store the player state and then you can just pass an instances of this class rather than 16 separate variables